# Showing a ring has no non-zero nilpotents via a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\theta\colon R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism. If each of $\ker{\theta}$ and $\operatorname{im}{\theta}$ has the property that its only
nilpotent element is $0$, show that the same is true for $R$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $r \in R$ is nilpotent, then $\phi(r)$ is nilpotent in $\mathrm{im}(\phi)$, hence zero. But then $r$ is in the kernel ... I think you can finish the proof now.